# Using keyword or wake word to activate Tkinter window in python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I found this amazing wake-word program called Porcupine. I got it to work and want to implement it into a Tkinter window. The idea is to have a state of on/off with the wake word turning it on. I have working code but the problem is that no matter where I put the listener in the code it will not make the window until I use the wake word.

I want the following behavior: I would like the window to be created and to appear and then to run the wake-word module so I can change the self.state variable. This wake word will then put me in a loop that will create other frames and features. I am assuming there is a threading solution but I could not figure it out.

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading
import ttk
import os

import sys
sys.path.append('Porcupine/demo/python')

import porcupine__demo

class FullscreenWindow:

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = False
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.configure(background='black')

        self.listen()

        print(self.state)

    def listen(self):
        self.state = porcupine_demo.listen_for_keyword()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = FullscreenWindow()
    w.tk.mainloop()
```

The method *.listen_for_keyword() is a method I wrote that returns True when the wake word is captured.

Answer (score 1):

I found an amazing blog post that answers this question. I have changed their code to reflect my needs. The blog is [here](https://gordonlesti.com/use-tkinter-without-mainloop/):

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading

import sys
sys.path.append('Porcupine/demo/python')

import porcupine_demo

class App(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, tk_root):
        self.root = tk_root
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        listening = True
        while listening:
            self.state = porcupine_demo.listen_for_keyword()
            if self.state:
                print("heard you:",self.state)
                LABEL = Label(self.root, text="Hello, world!")
                LABEL.pack()

ROOT = Tk()
ROOT.configure(background='black')
APP = App(ROOT)
ROOT.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The porcupine package comes with a demo of how to use porcupine in a non-blocking mode, which is necessary to allow `mainloop` to process tkinter events. The key is to attach a callback to the audio stream.

I've never used porcupine before so I don't know how well this works in the real world, but it works for me on my mac, and doesn't require explicit threading.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/tmp/Porcupine/binding/python")

import Tkinter as tk
import struct
from datetime import datetime
from porcupine import Porcupine
import pyaudio

library_path = "/tmp/Porcupine/lib/mac/x86_64/libpv_porcupine.dylib"
model_file_path = "/tmp/Porcupine/lib/common/porcupine_params.pv"
keyword_file_paths = ["/tmp/Porcupine/words_mac.ppn",]
num_keywords = len(keyword_file_paths)
sensitivities = [0.5] * num_keywords

class TkPorcupine(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.initialize_ui()
        self.initialize_porcupine()

    def initialize_ui(self):
        self.state = False
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.text = tk.Text(self.root, width=60, height=8)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.root, orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def initialize_porcupine(self):
        self.porcupine = Porcupine(library_path, model_file_path,
                                   keyword_file_paths=keyword_file_paths,
                                   sensitivities=sensitivities)
        self.audio_stream = pyaudio.PyAudio().open(
            rate=self.porcupine.sample_rate,
            channels=1,
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self.porcupine.frame_length,
            input_device_index=None,
        stream_callback=self.audio_callback)
        self.audio_stream.start_stream()

    def audio_callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        if frame_count >= self.porcupine.frame_length:
            pcm = struct.unpack_from("h" * self.porcupine.frame_length, in_data)
            result = self.porcupine.process(pcm)
            if num_keywords == 1 and result:
                message = '[%s] detected keyword' % str(datetime.now())
                self.text.insert("end", message + "\n")
                self.text.see("end")
            elif num_keywords > 1 and result >= 0:
                message = '[%s] detected keyword #%d' % (str(datetime.now()), result)
                self.text.insert("end", message + "\n")
                self.text.see("end")

        return None, pyaudio.paContinue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo = TkPorcupine()
    tk.mainloop()
```